# MonoDevelop and/or MonoTouch bug?

Tags: c#, xna, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monogame

When trying to compile some code, which had been compiling fine before with no errors, I started getting an error about a class not existing in a namespace.

I know this was compiling before just fine and I had not modified it, the Mac I was using just went to sleep, I woke it up again and found this error occuring.

The error is as follows:

> 'The Type or namespace
>   'ContentManager' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content'. Are
>   you missing an assembly reference?'

Before the mac went to sleep this code was running fine, so I'm wondering if that's a link between the two. I have chekced and I am 100% certain that ContentManager does in fact exist in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content, even MonoDevelop is able to take me to its declaration so I know for sure it's not the code that's broken.

I tried unloading/reloading the project (MonoGame.Framework.iOS) into the solution but that didnt help, also tried deleting the pidb file to it, still no results.

This is actually the second time this has happened, I think last time I just deleted the project and started fresh, but I really don't want to do that this time.

So any ideas on fixing this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a "clean" before you do a build. That is: select "rebuild" instead of "build"; or select "clean" and then select "build"; or close your IDE and delete the "bin" and "obj" directories and then try your build again.

Try checking that assembly reference actually exists in your game project.

Do any of your projects exist on a network share?

Answer (score 4):

If you upgraded to MonoTouch 4.0, you need to also upgrade your Mono to 2.10